# Notification not showing up when app is open

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, foregroundnotification

Notification is not showing when app is running.
It works when app is closed.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        PrefManager.setStringPreferences ( Constants.REGID, token );
        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
//        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent( Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

//                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
//                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, pushNotification);
//                } else {
//                    // image is present, show notification with image
//                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, pushNotification, imageUrl);
//                }
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


      //Showing notification with text only

    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }


     //Showing notification with text and image

    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context,String title,String message,String timeStamp,Intent intent,String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
}
```

In `handleDataMessage()` when app is not in background I put code of `showNotificationMessage()`. But when I put `showNotificationMessage()` function there notification is not showing whether the app is background or foreground.

When I comment that function notification appears but only when app is in background.

How to show notification when app is foreground?

Answer (score 6):

By default notification is shown only if app is not in foreground.

If you want to show notification in tray when app is in foreground add custom method to show notification using NotificationCompat.Builder

and call that method in onMessageReceived like

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
    Log.d(TAG, "Objects: " + remoteMessage.getNotification());
    generateNotification(getApplicationContext(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

Here is method

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String msg) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String channelId = "channel-fbase";
        String channelName = "demoFbase";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            int color = 0x008000;
            mBuilder.setColor(color);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }
        mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg));

        mBuilder.setContentTitle(msg);
        mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        //If you don't want all notifications to overwrite add int m to unique value
        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
        mNotificationManager.notify(m, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: it work but notification doesn't remove when clicked,
user have to remove the notification with remove button

Comment: hi @KasyfulAnwar you can call: `mNotificationManager.cancel(m)` inside remove button listener.
here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification#Removing

Comment: the `m` is the notification id, the one that  `int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have aded Firebase Service in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

send your notification with `Data` object only instead of `Notification` .

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a notification in kill state then you are using notification payload object. In the foreground, you have to add the code of show notification. You have to write notification code inside the notification:

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            //Show Notfication
        }
```

For more details, check out official link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 0):

In my case (android 8.0 and later) the problem was that the notification was sent to a notification channel I didn't create within the app.
The notification payload was something like the one below:

```kotlin
const payload = {
    "token": deviceToken,
    "notification": {
      "title": senderFullName,
      "body": senderFullName + ": " + message
    },
    "data": {
      "senderId": senderId,
      "body": senderFullName + ": " + message,
      "type": "chatNotification"
    },
    "android": {
      "collapse_key": "chat_message_notification",
      "notification": {
        "channel_id": "chat_notifications_channel",
        "imageUrl": senderImageUrl
      }
    }
```

However, my app code didn't create the corresponding `chat_notifications_channel`, once created everything turned out fine.

```kotlin
 private fun createChatNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = getString(R.string.direct_messages_notification_channel)
            val descriptionText = getString(R.string.chat)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            // This is the key line
            val channel =
                NotificationChannel("chat_notifications_channel", name, importance).apply {
                    description = descriptionText
                }
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you already setup config. don't forget to add ***priority*** in the `<service.. />` section, like this :

```
<service
    android:name="YOUR_CLASS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
       ....
    </intent-filter>
</servive>
```